# Search multiple field in MongoDB with MeteorJS

Tags: meteor

I am beginner in programming and interested to learn MeteorJS. I want to search category_name and subcategory_name by keyword or alphabet.:)

This is my code.

```
collections: subcategory
{
    _id:"ZbwCsJEMi2DesyJA7",
    category_name: "ICT",
    subcategory_name: "Laptop"
}

subcategory.js

Template.Subcategory.events({
     "keyup .searchbox": function(event){
           var query = event.target.value;
           Session.set('query', query);
     }
});

Template.Subcategory.helpers({
     subcategory: function(){
         var filter = {sort: {}};
         var query = Session.get('query');
         filter.sort[Session.get('sortby')] = 1;
         return Subcategory.find({ subcategory_name: new RegExp(query, 'i')} , filter ); 
    }
});
```

Comment: your problem is not defined properly. did you get any error? please explain your problem as specific as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for `$or` operator:

```
var queryRegexp = new RegExp(query, 'i');

return Subcategory.find({
    $or: [
        { category_name: queryRegexp },
        { subcategory_name: queryRegexp }
    ]
} , filter);
```

Official Mongo's documentation for $or: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

Comment: There is exactly what I been searched. Thanks for your help.. :)

Comment: Glad to help) Then it would be nice from you to mark this answer as accepted by pressing tick under down-vote triangle

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a text index in Mongo. You can do this in Meteor still I think with something like this:

```
MyCollection._ensureIndex({
  "$**": "text"
});
```

The above uses a wildcard but you can be more specific. See https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/index-text/ for more info.

For larger collections I tend to pass a text search query through a subscriptions so it can be performed on the server.

Assuming you want to show a list of things and allow users to filter them with the search box, you could do something like this:

```
Meteor.publish('MyCollection', function (searchTerm) {

  return searchTerm ? MyCollection.find() : MyCollection.find({ $text: {$search: searchTerm} });

});
```

On the client, assuming you're using template-level subscriptions, you could set up your subscription like this:

```
Template.Subcategory.onCreated(function(){
   var self = this;

   // requires the reactive-var package
   self.searchTerm = new ReactiveVar(false);

   self.autorun(function(){
        self.subscribe( "MyCollection", self.searchTerm.get() );
    });

});
```

It'd then just be a case of setting your search term:

```
Template.Subcategory.events({
    'keyup .searchbox': function(e,t){
        var inputValue = e.currentTarget.value,
            //you could set an arbitrary minimum search term length like so
            searchTerm = inputValue.length > 1 ? inputValue : false;
        t.searchTerm.set(searchTerm);
    }
});
```

There's a couple of caveats on relying on the subscriptions so heavily like this. For example, if your collections are scoped globally on the client you run the risk of multiple subscriptions to the same collection giving you results you might not want to render within your list. Nevertheless, I quite like this approach. Food for thought.

Comment: This also one of the solution. Thanks for your help.. :)